# use sed to replace the regex match & the line before the match with a "-=+ REMOVED +=-"

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have a large, and I mean large log of over 1.9 million lines.
I need to regex to replace all lines that do not contain the word "Never" and the preceding line and then replace with -=+ REMOVED +=-.  bellow is an example from the log.

```
2013-09-17-01:02:43 User: ID_123456@some.tld  
2013-09-17-01:02:43 Last login time: Never  
2013-09-17-01:02:43 User: ID_123458@some.tld  
2013-09-17-01:02:43 Last login time: 2013-09-16  
2013-09-17-01:02:43 User: ID_123423@some.tld  
2013-09-17-01:02:43 Last login time: 2013-09-15
```

SO the user has a login time, remove the line and the line prior for the email address. Final output should look like

```
2013-09-17-01:02:43 User: ID_123456@some.tld  
2013-09-17-01:02:43 Last login time: Never  
-=+ REMOVED +=-  
-=+ REMOVED +=-  
-=+ REMOVED +=-  
-=+ REMOVED +=-
```

Should be easy, but I have been beating my brains on it for the last hour.

I would prefer to use sed as I am trying to learn more, but am open to anything...

Comment: If any of those support negative lookbehind, `\G` and `\K`, you could use this: [link](http://www.regex101.com/r/jU1sI2).

Comment: Why do you like `-=+ REMOVED +=-`, isn't it better to just remove the line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed '$!N;/\n.*Never/!s/.*/-=+ REMOVED +=-/mg'  file
```

Comment: can you please explain more this ?

Answer (score 1):

This can make it:

```
$ rm="-=+ REMOVED +=-"
$ awk -v rm="$rm" 'BEGIN{OFS="\n"}NR%2{a=$0; next} $0~/Never/ {print a,$0; next}{print rm,rm}' a
2013-09-17-01:02:43 User: ID_123456@some.tld  
2013-09-17-01:02:43 Last login time: Never  
-=+ REMOVED +=-
-=+ REMOVED +=-
-=+ REMOVED +=-
-=+ REMOVED +=-
```

#### Explanation

- `-v rm="$rm"` is used to store the "removed" text.
- `BEGIN{OFS="\n"}` defines the lines separator.
- `NR%2{a=$0; next}` in case of odd line, store the line in the `a` var.
  $0~/Never/ {print a,$0; next}{print rm,rm}'`in case the line contains "Never", print the previous line (stored in`a`and the current one). Otherwise, print`removed` text twice.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It works, but the one liner I checked is faster and cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Another awk

```
awk '/User:/ {u=$0} /Last/ {if (/Never/) {print u"\n"$0} else {print v"\n"v}}' v="-=+ REMOVED +=-" file
```